# laravel use count/sum method after groupBy

Tags: php, laravel, count, group-by, sum

When I use `count` or `sum` method, I get the wrong result.

For example:

```
Member::groupBy('id')->count()
```

I only get result 1, in another method

```
Member::count()
```

I get the right result.

I get wrong result when use `sum` method.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14123

Forgot to say, My laravel  version info:

```
Laravel Framework version 5.1.40 (LTS)
```

**Actually problem in project**

I have a  **recharge log table**.

*1.pay log table*

```
CREATE TABLE pay_logs (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   amount decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
   pay_sn varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   join_date int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

*1.1 pay log talbe data*

```
INSERT INTO pay_logs (id, amount, pay_sn, join_date)
VALUES
  (1,10.00,'aabbcc',1466753291),
  (2,10.00,'aabbcc',1466753292),
  (3,20.00,'bbccdd',1466753292),
  (4,30.00,'ccddee',1466753292);
```

2.description

In pay_log table, the 1 and 2 record is same. So when wants to filter the results by the actually recharge success time, I just need one record, so I use groupBy operation.

My wrong operation

```
DB::table('pay_log')
 ->whereBetween('joinDate',[$beginToday,$endToday])
 ->where('isSucceed','=',1)
 ->where('type','=',1)
 ->groupBy('pay_sn');
 ->count();
```

Finally,solve it.

```
$query = DB::table('pay_log')
 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as num'))
 ->whereBetween('joinDate',[$beginToday,$endToday])
 ->where('isSucceed','=',1)
 ->where('type','=',1)
 ->groupBy('pay_sn');
```

ps: if use Eloquent ORM

modify `->mergeBindings($query)` to `->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())`

**Test Example（*discard*）**

1. create table sql

   `CREATE TABLE members (
       id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       name varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
       amount decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
2. test data

   `INSERT INTO hc_members (id, name, amount) VALUES
       (1,'aaa',10.00),
       (2,'bbb',10.00),
       (3,'ccc',10.00);`
3. test result

In my hope, when I use the method `Member::groupBy('name')->count()`

I want **result 3**

actually it **returns 1**.

when I use the method `Member::groupBy('name')->sum('amount')`

I want **result 30.00**

actually it **returns 10.00**

**Thanks for your answer to help me solve the problem!**

Comment: Why not use `count(Member::groupBy('id')->get())`?

Comment: Because the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` offers a `->count()` for a specific reason.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy But that doesn't seem to give correct results when combined with `groupBy()`

Comment: @aldrin27 thank you for your answer. As you said, I can use your method (but i get 500 error, maybe out of memory, get too many data, I think it's not necessary, I just need to get how many records it has) 

I have same proble with `sum` method,how can i solve it.

Comment: @Uchiha I've edited my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an issue with laravel because `Member::groupBy('id')->count()` will return the count of number of results for each id. (Laravel is returning only the first row from the query result.)

Try running this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate FROM members GROUP BY 'id'
```

It will return a count of the number of rows for each (id) aggregate. This is the query executed when you call `Member::groupBy('id')->count()` and laravel, expecting only one row, returns the count of the first aggregate.

If you want a count of the distinct ids, you can call

```
Member::distinct('id')->count('id')
```

This is the same reason your sum query also returns 10. The query returns the sum of 'amount' for a group with the same 'name'.

To get the sum of all amounts, simply call,

```
Member::sum('amount');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How can I get the row num.

sql:
`select count(*) from memebr group by id`

how to write in laravel

Comment: That's the query executed when you call `Member::groupBy('id')->count()`. If you want to get a count of the distinct ids, you can call `Member::select('id')->distinct()->count('id')`. (I'm assuming that's the result you require)

Comment: And whenever you call `get()`, you are essentially executing a query which returns a collection of the query results. This can usually consume all your memory and hang your application. On the other hand, until you call `get()` or a similar function, your query is just a query. It's not executed and you don't have to worry about a huge collection finishing off your memory.

Comment: You said you expect '30' but how do you expect to get that result? Do you wish to sum over the all amounts or something else, because that's the only way you can get that result in this case.

Comment: thans for your professional answer. I'll edit my problem that why I have to use groupBy before `count` or `sum` method. Sorry for my ambiguous description.