# Count user_id in a table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I want to use the following query.

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(`user_id`) AS total, SUM(`status` = 'Done') as done 
    FROM posts GROUP BY `name`, `user_id`, `status`
```

But when I implemented this...

```
Post::selectRaw('count(user_id) as total')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(status = "Done") as done')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

My data table doesn't display any data. Is there something wrong in my query?

Comment: use the ``toSql`` method to see what query your builder generates.

Comment: There is a sum and count functions in laravel (search for aggregate function laravel) you can use them and you can use this `->select(DB::raw('SUM(status = "Done") AS done')))` head to those 2 answers which can help you [Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424949/laravel-query-builder-sum-method-issue) and [Link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005224/laravel-use-count-sum-method-after-groupby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select(DB::raw('count(user_id) as total'))->selectRaw('SUM(status = "Done") as done')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Since you didnt provide any info about the models, migrations or logic, im guessing that you have everything else set up correctly.

Also the links that [Mohamed Bdr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15153326/mohamed-bdr) added are great examples and I recommend checking them out.

Comment: I got this error when trying your code ```undefined property:stdClass::$id```

Comment: Try dd($posts) or print_r($posts); and let me know what pops up

Comment: im using print_r($posts);  and the page shown ```Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 24 [done] => 3 ) ) )```

Comment: So stdClass is just a empty class that you fill when you need it, you can read more here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php?rq=1) . In your instance your count is 24 and the sum is 3. Are you passing any $id variable that may be interfering, in the route, or controller?

Comment: ah yes, im passing $row->$id for CRUD action in datatable, what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Well the $id is returning null, $row is also probably null (Im guessing), so see why is that and there is your problem, try and fix it and best of luck.